# How to remove popup warning in Sublime Linter?

Tags: sublimetext3, eslint, sublimelinter

I like that on save, Sublime Linter will put a red dot in the column, an outline around the error, and an error warning in the bottom of the window. However, I don't like that on save, it gives the warning in a popup. I've been googling and can't tell what setting makes this happen. Anyone know what I need to do? Thanks

[image: Popup Warning]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! Needed to uncheck `SublimeLinter > Show Errors on Save`

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that you need to set:

`"tooltips": false` within your `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings`

in order to avoid getting this tooltips which you can see below:

[image]

They may appear when hoovering over an error.